# Operation on Sets (slightly related to power set)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request

I am interested in an set-theoretic operation (which is potentially related to the [Power Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) $\mathcal{P} (X)$).

Let's say, $X=\{a,b\}$, then I want an operation $\mathcal{Q_n} (X)$, with the following property:

$$
\mathcal{Q_0}(X)=\{\{\}\} \\
\mathcal{Q_1}(X)=\mathcal{Q_0}(X) \cup \{\{a\},\{b\}\} \\
\mathcal{Q_2}(X)=\mathcal{Q_1}(X) \cup\{\{a,a\},\{a,b\},\{b,b\}\} \\
\mathcal{Q_3}(X)=\mathcal{Q_2}(X) \cup\{\{a,a,a\},\{a,a,b\},\{a,b,b\},\{b,b,b\}\} \\
\mathcal{Q_4}(X)=\mathcal{Q_3}(X) \cup\{\{a,a,a,a\},\{a,a,a,b\},\{a,a,b,b\},\{a,b,b,b\},\{b,b,b,b\}\} \\
...
$$

That means, for every order $n$, it contains every combintation of elements from $X$ up to $n$ elements. In particular, it allows for multiple appearances of the same element (which is in contrast to the Power Set).

> **Question:** What is the name of the operation $\mathcal{Q_n}(X)$?

Comment: If you want repetition of elements, then you need to be considering multisets, as $\{a,b,b,b\} = \{a,b\}$, etc. Then you might call $\mathcal{Q}_n(X)$ the "$n$-th multi-powerset iterate" or some other convoluted name. If you actually want everything to be a set, then simply $\mathcal{Q}_n(X) = \mathcal{P}(X)$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: I think what your looking for is: $\mathcal{Q_0}(X)=\{\text{0-tuples from}\ X^0\}=\{X^0\}=\{\emptyset\},\mathcal{Q_{n+1}}(X)=\mathcal{Q_n}(X)\cup\{\text{n+1-tuples from}\ X^{n+1}\}=\mathcal{Q_n}(X)\cup X^{n+1}$. This takes into account, cardinality-wise, the number of combinations of elements from $X$.

Comment: number of combinations of elements from $X$ up to $n$ elements.*